# How do you replace a non-failed disk in a BTRFS single profile pool?

Tags: linux, btrfs

I created a BTRFS pool with three 1 TB disks using the single profile, then balanced the data across all of them. It looks like this

```
Label: none  uuid: 5ff93463-e45e-4b46-8d94-c22a8e926813
    Total devices 3 FS bytes used 615.76GiB
    devid    1 size 931.51GiB used 206.03GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 207.00GiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    3 size 931.51GiB used 206.03GiB path /dev/sdd
```

Let's say I want to replace one of the disks with a larger disk (/dev/sdc for example). How do I get the data off of /dev/sdc so I can remove it from the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data off the disk you want to remove, use the `btrfs device remove` command. For example:

```
btrfs device remove /dev/sdc /SOME/MOUNTPOINT
```

The above command will first move the data off the disk, and then remove the device from the pool. The catch is that the device being removed must not be the one used to mount the filesystem.

For more info, run `man btrfs-device`

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that the `remove` command also took care of moving the data off the disk as well. If I wanted to remove the disk that the pool is mounted by (/dev/sdb) would I just have to remount the pool using one of the other disks and then doing the `remove` on /dev/sdb?

Comment: Yes. You can mount the entire filesystem using any of the disks in the pool.